# Using local storage to keep sidebar's position

Tags: javascript, css, html, menu, local-storage

I currently have a simple toggle button that collapses/expands my navigation sidebar:

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="extend">
             <button class="collapse-toggle"></button>
   <ul>
     <li></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.collapse-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#sidebar-wrapper').toggleClass("extend collapsed"); //you can list several class names

    e.preventDefault();
     });
 </script>
```

I want to use local storage to remember if the menu is collapsed or open every time the user reloads.  Every local storage tutorial / answer / etc. isn't quite fitting with my *existing* javascript approach at collapsing the menu, which I'd like to keep.

How can I make this work?

Comment: I dont see localstorage being used in your code. What have you tried?

Comment: Tried hacking together a handful of the responses in the following, but I'm just not too saavy.

https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-local-storage-with-javascript/

https://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/d/273681-how-to-persist-collapse-showhide-state-of-toggle-with-localstorage

http://mrbool.com/html5-local-storage-and-session-storage/26282

This seemed the closest?:
https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/issues/896

Comment: Usually MDN is the first place you should be looking if you need to find something useful and up to date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

Comment: fixed https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by reading the value in localStorage when the user visits the page. If a value is present, set the menu to the state (either open or closed). When no value is present, remove the `collapsed` class from the menu. This is also a fix for when the page is initially loaded. The menu then opens.

On each menu toggle, the state is saved in localStorage. When the user re-visits the page there will be a value stored in localStorage and the menu is displayed according to the state.

As localStorage doesn't work on Stack Overflow, see [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roycode/vsg0Lzkr/32) to see it in action. Here's a copy of the code.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  // Code responsible for setting localStorage and toggling when toggle button is clicked.
  $('.collapse-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    // localStorage.setItem('menu-closed', !$('#sidebar-wrapper').hasClass('collapsed'));
    $('#sidebar-wrapper').toggleClass('collapsed');
  });

  // Code responsible for reading the state of the menu out of localStorage
  // var state = localStorage.getItem('menu-closed');
  var state = "false"  // simulate localStorage

  // When localStorage is not set, open the menu.
  if (state === null) {
    $('#sidebar-wrapper').removeClass('collapsed');
  } else {
    // When localStorage is set, Save the state to the variable closed
    // Here set closed to a boolean true/false value instead of a string "true" or "false"       
    var closed = state === "true" ? true : false;

    // When the state of the menu is not closed, remove the collapsed class from the sidebar.
    if (!closed) {
      $('#sidebar-wrapper').removeClass('collapsed');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus,
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  background: #2c0963;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


/* Sidebar Collapse */

.extend {
  width: 260px !important;
}

.collapsed {
  width: 65px !important;
}

.collapse-toggle {
  margin-right: -31px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  width: 60px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 29px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 1600;
  opacity: 0.7;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.collapse-toggle:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>

<div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="extend collapsed">
  <button class="collapse-toggle">
      <span style="color:#25dbde; padding-right: 5px;">&#x2039;</span>        <span style="color:#d9d8d8; padding-left: 4px;">&#x203A;</span>
    </button>

  <ul id="menu">
    <li style="color: #fff;">Item 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In my menu, I'm actually not hiding it completely, just minifying it using width and transition styling, so I've substituted in my own classes.   This IS working (ish), although upon reload, it loads the extended menu and then collapses it a second later.

Comment: Yes, I saw that eventually in my example too. What you can do to prevent the menu from changing state is to hide the menu upon default and showing it based on the setting or when there is no setting at all. (I assume here that open is the default) Let me know if that's helpful enough or if you'd like me to adjust the example to fit your situation.

Comment: Yea, I'm still not getting it.  I stripped it down to my baseline starting point in this JSfiddle just to remove any confusion of the desired functionality.  Should stick open when open, closed when closed (on page reloads) https://jsfiddle.net/pvan1201/ar3q2sdg/15/

Comment: The best way I see to go around the opening and closing of the menu is to set the default state to closed. Then when the page is loaded, things move, so it won't be so apparent that the menu opens. Here's an update of your JSFiddle with this default behaviour. Let me know if this is what you are looking for and I'll update my answer to reflect that. https://jsfiddle.net/roycode/vsg0Lzkr/26

Comment: If it's helpful we can open a stack overflow chat and discuss the issue further. Let me know if you would like to do that?

Comment: This is perfect, and I like that solution to work around that loading movement.  Many thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I'll update my answer with the latest code of the JSFiddle to reflect our discussion here.

Comment: @RoyScheffers  Hey I tried your code and my one collapses and expands on page load. Can you please take a look? Here's the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63327866/sidebar-collapses-and-expands-on-page-load-after-storing-state-in-localstorage

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example:

```
if(!localStorage.getItem("toggle")) {
    // Check if theres anything in localstorage already
    localStorage.setItem("toggle", "true");
} else {
    if(localStorage.getItem("toggle") === "true") {
    // toggle was on, turning it off
    localStorage.setItem("toggle", "false");
  }
    else if(localStorage.getItem("toggle") === "false") {
    // toggle was off, turning it on
    localStorage.setItem("toggle", "true")
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cwq4rvsy/25/

Comment: thanks so much. Can you help me understand what's happening here?  Because it spits out a browser modal saying "Toggle is now set to: true".  Should I be replacing "toggle" with the button class "collapse-toggle"?

Comment: When the page loads you have to check if there's anything stored in localStorage.getItem("toggle") - if it's true you should set the CSS class to display the navigation.

If it isn't set - do nothing.

Now that toggle button in the JSFIDDLE works as it should, so you can delete the ALERT line that proves the code is functioning.

Comment: Got it.  Currently, it's not saving the toggle settings on refresh - does it matter that I'm running on a local environment?

Comment: Delete this line, it is useless, it's just to proove that it is working: ***alert("Toggle is now set to: " + localStorage.getItem("toggle"));*** The localstorage is working at my end, is it not working for you?

Comment: It is in the jsfiddle, but not on our site.  Wondering if the content is loading before it reads the localstorage, or perhaps some jquery is stomping on top