# CSS loading before JS is causing an unwanted effect

Tags: javascript, css, performance, local-storage, user-experience

Continuation of a [question I posted the other day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51695964/using-local-storage-to-keep-sidebars-position/51696429?noredirect=1#comment90357213_51696429), which was gracioiusly answered.

I'm using localstorage for calling the selected state of a "collapsed" or "extended" sidebar. However, when reloading a page with a stored "collapsed" size, the sidebar first loads at full width and then transitions to collapsed as the rest of the page loads.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pvan1201/ar3q2sdg/20/) of what I'm using (however, the css/javascript delay issue is not seen here, so I supposed this is just for reference).

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  // Code responsible for setting localStorage and toggling when toggle button is clicked.
  $('.collapse-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    localStorage.setItem('menu-closed', !$('#sidebar-wrapper').hasClass('collapsed'));
    $('#sidebar-wrapper').toggleClass('collapsed');
  });

  // Code responsible for reading the state of the menu out of localStorage
  var state = localStorage.getItem('menu-closed');

  // When localStorage is not set, open the menu.
  if (state === null) {
    $('#sidebar-wrapper').removeClass('collapsed');
  } else {
    // When localStorage is set, Save the state to the variable closed
    // Here set closed to a boolean true/false value instead of a string "true" or "false"          
    var closed = state === "true" ? true : false;
    $('#sidebar-wrapper').addClass('collapsed');
    // When the state of the menu is not closed, remove the collapsed class from the sidebar.
    if (!closed) {
      $('#sidebar-wrapper').removeClass('collapsed');
    }
  }
});
```

I've tried moving the JS as far above the css as possible, but to no avail. I've thought about swapping between two completely different sidebar divs, hiding the opposing one on toggle select, but then I miss out on a nice css transition, and feel like it's not the cleanest solution.

What can I do?

Comment: instead of document.ready, you can use the smallest block i.e.  just after `.collapse-toggle` is loaded

Comment: window.ready waits for all assets to be loaded. You can try that instead of document.ready which just waits for the document to become ready.

Comment: And I guess the transition is with css. If so, you can add the `html` tag a class in `window.load` (`loaded` for example) and the transition you should define under that class, for example `html.loaded #sidebar-wrapper { transition: ...  }`. Make sense for you?

Comment: Hmm, none of these are working. The problem is occurring (if I'm not mistaken), due to the fact that my js that has the expand/contract toggle switch has to come after the body to function, yet should theoretically be placed before the body to fire first??

Comment: @PVan hey could you solve this issue? I'm going through the same thing.