# Sidebar collapses for a second and expands on page load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this sidebar which expands or collapses on a button click. Now I've successfully stored it's state in `localStorage` and it's working fine except there's a slight issue.

When the page loads and there is no state saved in `localStorage`, the sidebar `collapses` for a split second and `expands`. `Expand` is supposed to be the default state when there is no state stored in `localStorage`. I don't want it to `collapse` first and then `expand`. I just want the page to load with the sidebar `expanded`.

I have been trying to solve the issue with my own code. But it didn't work then I combined my code with of of SO's posts. It still doesn't work.

Full Code: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/zakero/pen/dyMovBz)

Here's the code(please note that `localStorage` won't work in SO):

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

    if (typeof window.isMinified === "undefined") {
      window.isMinified = false;
    }


    const body = $('#body');
    $("#sidebar-toggler").on("click", function () {
        
        if (window.isMinified === false) {

            // localStorage.setItem('menu-closed', !$(body).hasClass("sidebar-minified"));
            body.removeClass("sidebar-minified-out").addClass("sidebar-minified");
            window.isMinified = true;

        } else {

            // localStorage.setItem('menu-closed', !$(body).hasClass("sidebar-minified"));
            body.removeClass("sidebar-minified").addClass("sidebar-minified-out");
            window.isMinified = false;

        }
            
    });

    const state = // localStorage.getItem('menu-closed');

    if (state === null) {

        $(body).removeClass('sidebar-minified');

    } else {

        const closed = state === "true" ? true : false;

        if (!closed) {
            $(body).removeClass('sidebar-minified');
        }

    }
});
```

```css
#body {
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

aside.left-sidebar{
  background-color: #2c0963;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar-minified-out .left-sidebar {
  width: 180px;
  transition: width .3s ease-in; 
}
.sidebar-minified .left-sidebar {
  width: 75px;
  transition: width .3s ease-in; 
} 


.sidebar-toggle {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="body" class="sidebar-minified sidebar-minified-out">
  <aside class="left-sidebar"></aside>

  <button id="sidebar-toggler" class="sidebar-toggle">Collapse/Expand</button>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can minimize the the flashing effect, by telling the browser to *repaint* just only one time, in one shot. BUT there will be always one initial size for Your `sidebar`: the size which has been defined inside Your markup.

In my example, I am using two `Observers` to track the style and size changes. Please, note the initial `sidebar` width. You may set the initial sidebar width equal to 0, or let it unassigned, or maybe You can style it the same size as Your expanded sidebar, but there will be always an initial repaint.

Finally, I strongly believe You need to remove the two initial classes from the `body`.

```js
$(function() {
  /* avoid SO unsecure operation error */
  var storage = (function () {
    return {
      setItem: function(k,v){try{return localStorage.setItem(k,v)}catch(e){return !1}},
      getItem: function(k){try{return localStorage.getItem(k)}catch(e){return null}}
    }; 
  })();
  
  log("jQuery DOM Ready");
  
  $("#sidebar-toggler").on("click", function() {
    var isMinified = !$("body").hasClass("sidebar-minified-out");
    $("body")
      .toggleClass("sidebar-minified", !isMinified)
      .toggleClass("sidebar-minified-out", isMinified);   
    storage.setItem('menu-closed', +!isMinified);
  });
  
  var closed = +storage.getItem('menu-closed');
  log('Closed: ' + !!closed);
  $("body")
    .addClass(closed ? "sidebar-minified" : "sidebar-minified-out")
    .css({"visibility": "visible"});
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
aside.left-sidebar{
  background-color: #2c0963;
  height: 100vh;
}
.sidebar-minified-out .left-sidebar {
  width: 180px;
  transition: width .3s ease-in; 
}
.sidebar-minified .left-sidebar {
  width: 75px;
  transition: width .3s ease-in; 
} 
.sidebar-toggle {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sidebar State</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="visibility: hidden;">
  <aside class="left-sidebar"></aside>
  <button id="sidebar-toggler" class="sidebar-toggle">Collapse/Expand</button>
  <div id="log" style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;padding:1em;"></div>
  <script>
    /* only debug functions inside this script block */
    function log(msg) {
      $("<div>").appendTo("#log").text(msg);
    }
    var mo = new MutationObserver(function (ml){
      for(var m of ml) {
        if (m.type == 'attributes') log('Body ' + m.attributeName + ' changed');
      }
    });
    mo.observe(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0], {attributes: true});
    var ro = new ResizeObserver(function (rl){
      for(var r of rl) {
        var w = r.contentRect.width;
        if(w<=75 || w>=180) log('Sidebar width: ' + r.contentRect.width);
      }
    });
    ro.observe(document.getElementsByClassName("left-sidebar")[0]);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

If You look at the messages logged by the *Observers*, You will notice that there is always a repaint, as mentioned above.

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63033934/4845566) solution of Your previous question: [Dark mode flickers a white background for a millisecond on reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63033412/dark-mode-flickers-a-white-background-for-a-millisecond-on-reload) I believe You can implement Your Sidebar toggler the same way.

Instead of applying the CSS class to the `body`, You can apply it to the `html`. Here is the **full code**:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    /* Render blocking script */
    var c = +localStorage.getItem('menu-closed');
    document.documentElement.classList.add(c ? 'sidebar-minified' : 'sidebar-minified-out');
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <aside class="left-sidebar"></aside>
  <button id="sidebar-toggler" class="sidebar-toggle">Collapse/Expand</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $("#sidebar-toggler").on("click", function (e) {
    var isMinified = !$("html").hasClass("sidebar-minified-out");
    $("html")
      .toggleClass("sidebar-minified", !isMinified)
      .toggleClass("sidebar-minified-out", isMinified);
    localStorage.setItem('menu-closed', +!isMinified);
  });
});
```

Your CSS will remain untouched beside of a small change (I just only removed the `#body` id).

Now, if You compare the *Observed* changes, You will notice that the second solution, which is using the blocking JS script in `head`, is showing only the initial Sidebar size, i.e.: the initial repaint is gone:

```
   1st solution                          2nd solution
==============================================================
    Sidebar width: 601                    Closed: false
    jQuery DOM Ready                      Sidebar width: 180
    Closed: false                         jQuery DOM Ready
    Body class changed
    Body style changed
    Sidebar width: 180
```

(Credits: [Roko C. Buljan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383904/roko-c-buljan)):

More information:

---

The debug functions in my first example are used just only to depict the sequence of the resize and restyle events inside the browser.

Here is some documentation about that *Observers*:

- [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)
- [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)

Comment: No idea what you did there. Copied your code and the whole body is blank. Then removed the visibility hidden style from body but then nothing happens when button is clicked.

Comment: Nah nothing's there.

Comment: @Zak: is this Plunker working for You? https://plnkr.co/edit/o50hNb41szym42Un?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview

Comment: Hey apparently I had the wrong stylesheet and script file path. It's working now and it's perfect. Can you please explain the JS code?

Answer (score 0):

It is the transition from the css that let the sidebar expand. If you remove the transistion you will see that the sidebar ist immediately expanded on page load. So for the first time you should set CSS classes without transitions.

Comment: Hey i dont think this is it. I just removed the transition but now it's faster than before. I mean it is not smoother. But it does collapse first then expands.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the transition via Javascript and enable it again for the click event:

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sy4co3ru/)

First remove the classes in the body tag:

```
<body id="body" class="">
    <aside class="left-sidebar"></aside>
    <button id="sidebar-toggler" class="sidebar-toggle">Collapse/Expand</button>
</body>
```

Just a few lines to change in the javascript:

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    if (typeof window.isMinified === "undefined") {
        window.isMinified = false;
    }

    const body = $('#body');
    $("#sidebar-toggler").on("click", function () {
        
        document.querySelector('.left-sidebar').style.transition = 'inherit';

        if (window.isMinified === false) {

            localStorage.setItem('menu-closed', !body.hasClass('sidebar-minified'));
            body.removeClass('sidebar-minified-out').addClass('sidebar-minified');
            window.isMinified = true;

        } else {

            localStorage.setItem('menu-closed', !body.hasClass('sidebar-minified'));
            body.removeClass('sidebar-minified').addClass('sidebar-minified-out');
            window.isMinified = false;

        }
            
    });

    const state = localStorage.getItem('menu-closed');

    if (state === null) {

        body.addClass('sidebar-minified');

    } else {

        const closed = state === "true" ? true : false;

        if (!closed) {
            body.addClass('sidebar-minified-out');
            document.querySelector('.left-sidebar').style.transition = 'none';
        }
        else {
            body.addClass('sidebar-minified');
        }

    }
});
```

The important changes in above code are two things:

```
// in the clickevent section: change the transistion to default behaviour
document.querySelector('.left-sidebar').style.transition = 'inherit';
```

Set the right class depending on state and disable transition:

```
// ...

if (state === null) {

    body.addClass('sidebar-minified');

} else {

    // ...

    if (!closed) {
        body.addClass('sidebar-minified-out');
        document.querySelector('.left-sidebar').style.transition = 'none';
    }
    else {
        body.addClass('sidebar-minified');
    }

}
```

*** **Update** ***

I refactored the code and optimized it a bit. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qn8vs32a/)
HTML:

```
<body id="body">
    <aside class="left-sidebar"></aside>
    <button id="sidebar-toggler" class="sidebar-toggle">Collapse/Expand</button>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#body {
    background: #fff;
    transition: all .3s;
}
aside.left-sidebar {
    background-color: #2c0963;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 75px;
}
.sidebar-minified-out .left-sidebar {
    width: 180px;
}
.sidebar-transitions .left-sidebar {
    transition: width .3s ease-in; 
} 
.sidebar-toggle {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    $("#sidebar-toggler").on("click", function () {
        
        localStorage.setItem('menu-closed', $('#body').hasClass('sidebar-minified-out'));

        $('#body').addClass('sidebar-transitions').toggleClass('sidebar-minified-out');
            
    });

    localStorage.getItem('menu-closed') === "true" ? $('#body').removeClass('sidebar-minified-out') : $('#body').addClass('sidebar-minified-out');

});
```

Comment: Hey. Now the sidebar takes up the whole screen as background and then collapses or expands. :| I don't think it's possible. I guess I'll need react or somethng to make it work lol

Comment: then you missed the `body.addClass('sidebar-minified')` line. Note that two lines changed from `removeClass` to `addClass`.

Comment: No. I tried with the code you provided mate. Is it working on your side? Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I tried it and its working. Give me a second to fiddle it...

Comment: Updated answer with jsfiddle link

Comment: I tried it again but there's a flicker where the sidebar covers the whole background. Can you please try to open the page in sublime text and refresh it

Comment: Tried. Doesn't work. It's like when there is no state saved in localStorage or if the state is expanded, then upon page load, the sidebar collapses first for a split second and then expands. Same issue as the OP. I'm sorry mate. You have been trying a lot.

Comment: Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: Don't think so. There will always be a moment, where the state is not defined. Maybe an overlaying splash screen for a second or playing with the opacity of the sidebar. But then I would prever the expanding animation upon page load.

Comment: Found this codepen. It has the same issue as mine but then again it is so fast, it's negligible. https://codepen.io/ellimccale/pen/XPKGJm

Answer (score 0):

How about moving the animation to a separate class lets say

```
.sidebar-animated{
   transition: width: 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

and removing it from anywhere else and then adding that class via timeout, so it gets added after the transition is done, you can use useTimeout with 0 seconds, like so,

```
setTimeout(() => {
    $('aside').addClass('sidebar-animated')    
},0)
```

Plus CSS uses Specificity to reach its element, so

```
.sidebar-minified-out .left-sidebar {
  width: 180px;
}

.sidebar-minified .left-sidebar {
  width: 75px;
}
```

Should be changed to this.

```
.sidebar-minified .left-sidebar {
  width: 75px;
} 

.sidebar-minified-out .left-sidebar {
  width: 180px;
}
```

because when you have both on the same element, it will take the later because they have the same specificity rule, give it a last shot, thats the last resort for me :D.

thats enough to make it work

https://codepen.io/menawer_cpe/pen/qBZbEdw

here is a working example,
Note: you have an issue with managing state when the sidebar collapsed at first, but thats something related to how you deal with the state.

Why useTimeout with 0? because it pushes the execution to what is called "event loop" making sure it executes after all javascript normal code is executed.

Comment: it still collapses first and then expands. Also, there's still a transition effect. But sometimes it's there and sometime its not!

Comment: Can you check it now, i added some delay, what kind of browser you are using.

Comment: Hey I'm using Chrome. Tried another one but still the same. I think it's not possible as a lot of methods have been tried by me and contributors here. I'll just scrap this functionality. Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: I noticed one more thing, i'll mention it in the answer

Comment: Now the collapsed state isnt stored. Collapse then reload, doesn't keep it collapsed. Mate, thanks a lot for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  if (window.isMinified === undefined) {
    window.isMinified = false;
  }

  const body = $('#body');
  $("#sidebar-toggler").on("click", function() {
  
    $('#body .left-sidebar').removeAttr("style");

    if (window.isMinified === false) {
    
      body.removeClass("sidebar-minified-out").addClass("sidebar-minified");
      window.isMinified = true;

    } else {

      body.removeClass("sidebar-minified").addClass("sidebar-minified-out");
      window.isMinified = false;

    }

  });

  var firstTime = true;
  var sidebar = $('#body aside.left-sidebar');
  const state = !(null); //localStorage.getItem('menu-closed');

  if (state === null) {
    $(body).removeClass('sidebar-minified');

  } else {

    if (firstTime) {
      sidebar.css('transition', 'none');
      firstTime = false;
    }

    const closed = state === "true" ? true : false;

    if (!closed) {
      $(body).removeClass('sidebar-minified');
    }

  }
});
```

```css
#body {
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

aside.left-sidebar {
  background-color: #2c0963;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar-minified-out .left-sidebar {
  width: 180px;
  transition: width .3s ease-in;
}

.sidebar-minified .left-sidebar {
  width: 75px;
  transition: width .3s ease-in;
}

.sidebar-toggle {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id="body" class="sidebar-minified sidebar-minified-out">
  <aside class="left-sidebar"></aside>

  <button id="sidebar-toggler" class="sidebar-toggle">Collapse/Expand</button>

</body>
```